# Set Objective-C property by string

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to set (or retrieve) an Objective-C property by a NSString... It is possible to use `NSSelectorFromString`, but I'd like an easier (and less hacky way) to do it... Something like

```
[object setProperty:@"propertyValue" named:@"propertyName"];
```

is equivalent to:

```
object.propertyName = @"propertyValue";
```

I don't really want to mess around with the `@"propertyName"` and turn it into a `@"setPropertyName:"` for the `NSSelectorFromString` command... I may have no other choice, but if anyone knows a better way to do this, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html). Your example would be `[object setValue:@"propertyValue" forKey:@"propertyName"]`.